# Ignore zero values at sorted in lambda

Tags: java, spring, lambda, java-8, comparator

I tried to ignore zero values when I sorted values if values are `0 0 4 2 1 7` it should be first `1 2 4 7 0 0`

```
List<PersonItem> collect = personLists.stream()
.sorted((p1,p2) -> 
    (p1.getCelebrityWeighting() == null ? 0 : p1.getCelebrityWeighting()) 
     - (p2.getCelebrityWeighting() == null ? 0 : p2.getCelebrityWeighting()))
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: If you have `null` values, they are better compared using `Comparator.nullsLast` rather than mapping them to `0` as a value.

Comment: you want to see 0/null values at the end of the sorted list, don't you?  Does this comparator work for you? .sorted((p1,p2) -> {
                if (p1 == null || p1.w() == 0) return 1; //
                if (p2 == null || p2.w() == 0) return -1; //
                return p1.w() - p2.w();
            })
suppose that p.w() is p.getCelebrityWeighting()

Comment: This question is not clear. Please add more details to your question first. This may also help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

**Sort with `null` values last**:

Note the `0` values will be first. This is `null` friendly.

```
personLists.sort(
    Comparator.comparing(
        PersonItem::getCelebrityWeighting,                 // key extractor, comparing by...
        Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder()))); // natural order, nulls last
```

> 0, 0, 1, 2, 4, 7, null, null

---

**Sort with `0` values last**:

Note this solution is not `null` friendly, the `getCelebrityWeighting()` must not be `null` and works if all `null` values are replaced with `0`. Mind the order in the comparator when you return 1`or`-1`.

```
personLists.sort((first, second) -> {
    if (first.getCelebrityWeighting() == 0) return 1;                       // 0 last
    if (second.getCelebrityWeighting() == 0) return -1;                     // 0 last
    return first.getCelebrityWeighting() - second.getCelebrityWeighting();  // standard
});
```

> 1, 2, 4, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0

---

**Sort with `0` and `null` values last**:

Combination of the samples above is `null` friendly:

```
personLists.sort(
    Comparator.comparing(
        PersonItem::getCelebrityWeighting,         // key extractor, comparing by...
        Comparator.nullsLast((first, second) -> {  // here you have weightings
             if (first == 0) return 1;             // 0 and then null last
             if (second == 0) return -1;
             return first - second;
        })));
```

> 1, 2, 4, 7, 0, 0, null, null

Comment: When both arguments are zero, a comparator must return zero.